# Persisting Explicit Data vs Binary Data (Performance) in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, performance, flutter, persistence

I'm facing a problem while developing a mobile application which requires me to persist some simple model data in Shared Preferences.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to persist the model in terms of performance / efficiency, for write and read operations:

- Deserialize to model and persist it with key-value for each model property (**Write** Operation), and then serialize it back (**Read Operation**)
- Serialize model into binary and persist with a pre-defined key by application side (**Write Operation**) and deserialize it back (**Read Operation**)

Also the model which I'm persisting is unique for the application so there aren't multiple models to persist on Shared Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

According to official flutter [website](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value):

"Only primitive types can be used: int, double, bool, string and stringList"

So if you want to store binary data you should consider using [sqlflite](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite)
which is a self-contained implementation of the famous `sqllite` database for flutter.